# Clojure destructuring returns weird thing

Tags: clojure

What is going on here:

```
(defn what [[a]]
  (print a b))
```

now if I call `(what "abid")` I get:

```
a [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Where does this come from? what are the numbers?

Comment: sure enough you're testing in the repl and you have a "global" _b_ set to [1 2 3 4 5]. if you eval _b_ on your repl isn't it `[1 2 3 4 5]`?

Comment: I agree. You namespace is probably "poluted".

Comment: what does "poluted" mean?

Comment: oh ya! your right! :-) an invisible b from last tests...

Comment: you can check what is bound in repl (in current ns) quite easily with `(clojure.repl/dir-fn *ns*)`, returns i.e. `(a b what)`

Comment: "Polluted" (or, I'd say, "cluttered") means that you have some stray bindings (~variables, but not really) defined in your REPL's namespace that you've forgotten about.

Comment: @birdspider very nice! this lists all the bindings (variables) in the current session! where could i learn more of cool things like this one? where have you found this?

Comment: @teymuri: I get most of my "oh nice" stuff for clojure via https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/ and various clj-related blogs

Comment: @teymuri:  also `(doc ...)` and `(source ...)`; I just "found" `dir-fn` via reading through `(source dir)` (I knew `dir` existed), it's kind of exploring clojure by repl

Answer (score 0):

You have **b** defined for sure before you define this function otherwise you would get

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: b in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:4:3)
```

try your code in new clojure repl with nothing else in it. And the **b** is source of that magic numbers.

E.G.:

```
(def b 5)
(defn what [[a]]
(print a b))
(what "abc")
a 5nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `b` is defined as `[1 2 3 4 5]` somewhere, this is functioning exactly how I'd expect it to.  Since `b` is otherwise undefined in the code you gave, we can only assume this is the case.

`a` is the first element of the first parameter to `what`.  For `(what "abcd")`, this is the lower-case character "a".